Azure data factory with terraform, stopping and starting triggers?
I'm experimenting with setting up Azure Data factory with Terraform and it seems to work well.
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory" "example" {
  name                = "example"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_pipeline" "example" {
  name            = "example"
  data_factory_id = azurerm_data_factory.example.id
}

resource "azurerm_data_factory_trigger_schedule" "example" {
  name            = "example"
  data_factory_id = azurerm_data_factory.example.id

  interval  = 5
  frequency = "Day"

  pipeline {
    name = azurerm_data_factory_pipeline.example.name
    }
}

However, in Microsofts documentation, they mainly use ARM and refer to using a powershell script to stop triggers, deploy and then start triggers again.
Is this necessary when using the terraform deployment? I could quite easily write a script to list all triggers in the adf and then stop, do tf apply and then start them again. However, this is not ideal, I would be better if only triggers related to changed pipelines are stopped/started. Not sure if I could somehow output them from the terraform plan command. Basically, if azurerm_data_factory_pipeline.example has been changed/updated in terraform, the azurerm_data_factory_trigger_schedule.example should be stopped and then started again.
Anyone else already solved this issue?

The configuration you're targeting may not be directly feasible with Terraform. During your setup experimentation, consider managing only the triggers linked to modified pipelines throughout a Terraform deployment. Employ a null_resource with local-exec provisioners for running pre-apply and post-apply scripts. The pre-apply script should deactivate the pertinent triggers, implement changes with 'terraform apply', and the post-apply script should reactivate the triggers. @Essej

I see, so this null_resource could effectivly execute a script then I suppose. Yes sadly ARM templates have to many limitations for us such as 256 parameter limit.

One issue here though is that it isnt necessarily the triggers that changes. The trigger should be stopped or started also if pipelines and possibly even datasets are changed? Also it seems that the local-exec is only executed on apply, not during planning.

Yes, null_resource can execute scripts effectively, but local-exec only runs during apply, not plan. To handle changes to pipelines and datasets, extend your script to check for changes in these components and manage the related triggers accordingly. Since ARM templates have limitations, using Terraform with null_resource is a viable workaround for your requirements @Essej
